# distributions with equal first and second raw moments

Tags: distributions, moments

I'm trying to understand the class of distributions for which the first (mean) and second (mean of squares) raw moments are equal. Consider the following trivial example

$$
x_1 = 0.5\\
x_2 = 1.2071067811865475\\
x_1 + x_2 == x_1^2 + x_2^2\\
$$

Is it possible to center and scale any distribution such that the first and second raw moments become equal ?

Comment: Because the means are equal, equality of the second moments implies equality of the variances. Thus, all you are doing is establishing the location and scale of the distribution.  This is essentially the class of *all* distributions when you allow for a linear change in the units of measurement. But taking your question literally, since the second raw moment cannot be negative, the answer clearly is "no" unless by "scale" you permit scaling by negative multiples (which is OK, but that's not usually what's understood by "scaling") and even then the answer is "no" for any zero-mean distribution.